# Sniff Packets on Local Network

Tags: networking, packet-sniffers

I have a network, consisting 4 PCs. All PCs are connected to a hub.

One of these PCs has two network interfaces which one of them is connected to the hub. and the other one in connected to the internet.

How can i configure this PC to sniff in the internal hub network, and capture all pockets and send them to the specific destination on internet? (I do not what this PC to change the source address of packets just destination address to the remote machine on the internet! so that when the packet arrived at the remote machine, it contains the address of one of other 3 PCs as the source)

IS it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want, but if you want to access an external network from your 3 pc, you should set the pc with two cards as the default gateway. On the pc with two cards you should also setup some kind of masquerading. However, at the destination point you'll never have the exact source address, but the addres of the pc doing the nat/pat translation.

Comment: i do not want to access an external network. i want to sniff packets inside a local network from another machine which is on the internet!

Comment: You can sniff the traffic from your machine with two cards and send it at regular interval. What kind of os is on your machine?

Comment: Actually i am just testing, do not have any OS preference, if required can install anything! I need to access all packets travelling inside the network so that a remote server could process them for some specific pastern (trying to implement simple remote IDS).

Comment: There is this soft http://www.pawelko.net/linux/17-Rpcapd-For-Linux with which you can send sniffed trafic to another machine. Or you can simply sniff to a file with tcpdump or wireshark and send it to a pc, but that won't be realtime.

Comment: Thank. Nice application. i checked it! as far as i notices it uses Remote Capture Protocol (RPCAP) which personally i do not know how it is implemented. i need to have same packet travelling inside the network to appear on remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly you want to "spy" the other computer? If you're on the same network, you can try to use Wireshark to capture all traffic going over a router.